# Ubuntu При вводе любой команде -bash command not found

Tags: ubuntu, bash, консоль

При вводе любой команды в терминале выдает постоянно ошибку:

```
-bash: open: command not found
-bash: awk: command not found
-bash: [: -ge: unary operator expected
-bash: awk: command not found
```

Что делать?

Comment: для начала проверить переменные окружения $PATH, проверить монтирование дисков, проверить наличие запускаемых программ.

Comment: А если ввести команду `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` команды начинают выполняться?

Comment: Убили скорее всего *.profile* в домашнем каталоге, хотя по идее должен быть глобальный... Может быть наоборот, что-то туда вписали, что рушит переменные окружения.